# Overlay fixed on top of div and keep position page scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've the following example below. When you click the yellow box, an overlay will be shown and it works fine. But when i then scroll down it ofc stays because it has a position fixed.

How can i make sure the overlay stay ontop of the `.div` when i scroll, aka so it "don't move"?

```js
$('.modal').css("top", $(".div").offset().top).css("left", $(".div").offset().left).css("width", $(".div").css("width")).css("height", $(".div").css("height"));

$(".div").click(function() {
  $('.modal').addClass("loading");
})
```

```css
.div {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  content: "";
}

body {
  height: 500px;
  background-color:black;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8) url('http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.modal.loading {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="modal"></div>
```

Comment: remove the fixed position

Answer (score 0):

Change your **position** to **absolute**.

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8) url('http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the fixed position of the modal with a absolute position , place the .modal in the .div

```js
$(".div").click(function() {
  $('.modal').addClass("loading");
})
```

```css
.div {
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8) url('http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.modal.loading {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
.div content
  <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this, tell if i'm doing something wrong.

First you need to change `position: fixed;` with `position: absolute;` in modal class.
Then put modal class div into  class div like this

```
<div class="div">
  <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
```

check snippet for running in action

```js
$(".div").click(function() {
  $('.modal').addClass("loading");
})
```

```css
.div {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8) url('http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

.modal.loading {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is basically my answer without the comment

Comment: yeah but i did first..sorry for that

Comment: you did first what?

Comment: i give answer first buddy

Comment: And Tony Nielson get his answer that's important

Comment: a couple a seconds before me but that isn't the problem the porblem is that you didn't explain what you did in there

Comment: @patelarpan you actually weren't even first. Look at the timestamps, your answer was posted a minute after madalinivascu

Comment: Sorry for that my mistake :)